# AWK - Using RT when RS is a regexp gives me the RS of the next match not the current

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I am trying to use gawk to extract paragraphs from a log and it is working perfectly up to the point where I want to include the record separator it found.

This is the command:

```
gawk --re-interval 'BEGIN{RS="[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,6} \\[[A-Z]*\\]";} /983a99f8-bec6-11e1-80dd-059a821d0b73/ {print $0}' full.log
```

If I add in print RT, $0, it prints the RT of the next match not the current match.

This is some sample text

```
9:08:06.899627 [DEBUG] <0.30065.3>@agent:1565 Recs to loop through:  [{agent_state,"OpenAcdAgent43","Jeff",
                            undefined,wrapup,
                            {call,"983a99f8-bec6-11e1-80dd-059a821d0b73",
                                voice,
                                {"8501112234","MorganGrimes"},
                                "9201",<0.30392.3>,[],
                                {client,"8221314","DCF",[],1340629596,
                                    1340629596},
                                [creole_general],
                                <0.30398.3>,outband,inband,inbound,10},
                            1340629658,undefined,"Default",1340629658
9:08:06.899707 [INFO] <0.168.0>@cpx_monitor:649 Down message for reference #Ref<0.0.16.137225> of <0.30064.3> due to normal
```

What I want to be 9:08:06.899627 [DEBUG] able to do is prepend 9:08:06.899627 [DEBUG] to my match but RS takes that away. I get 9:08:06.899707 [INFO]  instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because a record separator comes at the **end** of a record. So `9:08:06.899627 [DEBUG]` is the end of an empty record and `9:08:06.899707 [INFO]` is the end of the record that matches your GUID regex.

You need to save the previous `RT` and output the saved one.

```
gawk --re-interval 'BEGIN{RS="[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,6} \\[[A-Z]*\\]";} /983a99f8-bec6-11e1-80dd-059a821d0b73/ {print savedRT, $0} {savedRT = RT}' full.log
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! But out of curiosity how is it that the first record prints correctly if it saves what is after?

Comment: @edaniels: I'm not sure if I understand you, but this might answer you. The `print` statement is only executed when the regex matches, but it's tested for every input record. The assignment to `savedRT` is made for *every* record since there's no selector condition. The first record is empty so it doesn't match the regex and its `RT` is saved. Then the second record is processed which matches your regex so it and the saved `RT` are printed. Then *its* `RT` is saved for possible use with the next record. So to answer your question, the first record *isn't* printed - because it's empty.